# Read data from json

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, html

This is my JSON file

```
{
 "styleMapping": {
  "1": {
  "zIndex": 1,
  "StyleMappingCollection": {
    "636404903145791477": {
      "border": {
        "color": "#FF000000",
        "width": "Small",
        "type": "Solid"
      },
      "background": {
        "bgOption": "Image",
        "thumbOption": "Pointer",
        "opacity": 1.0,
        "bgColor": "#FFF5F5DC",
        "bgImage": "C:\Users\raj\Downloads\images\image.jpg",
      }
 }
}
```

i want to capture bgImage parameter in my javascript.

My script code is

```
 $http.get('Data//xyz.json').then(successCallback, errorCallback);

                function successCallback(response)
                {           
                   sliderCtrlPtr.sliderParams = response.data;
                   sliderCtrlPtr.sliderParams.height = response.data.deviceHeight;

                   console.log("After JSON read : ",sliderCtrlPtr.sliderParams);

                }
                function errorCallback(error)
                {
                    //error code                       
                }

                sliderCtrlPtr.GetsliderStyle = function () 
                {
                    if(sliderCtrlPtr.sliderParams != undefined)
                    {
                        var styleObj = sliderCtrlPtr.sliderParams;       
                        canvas.color = styleObj.StyleMappingCollection.
 636404903145791477.background.bgColor;
             }                       
          };
    }]);
})();
```

i want to retrieve bgColor or bgImage parameter from my json file in my script. How can I do that?

Comment: What are you getting in response? or are you even getting any? try using console.log in `successCallback` and `errorCallback` and check once.

Comment: Try styleObj.StyleMappingCollection[
 636404903145791477].background.bgColor

Comment: Also could you check if your JSON is proper? seems wrong to me or have you posted half of your JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the line should be. From the JSON provided which is not complete, I could only find this error!

```
sliderCtrlPtr.GetsliderStyle = function() {
    if (sliderCtrlPtr.sliderParams != undefined) {
      var styleObj = sliderCtrlPtr.sliderParams;
      canvas.color = styleObj["styleMapping"]["1"]["StyleMappingCollection"]
      ["636404903145791477"]["background"]["bgColor"];
      canvas.image = styleObj["styleMapping"]["1"]["StyleMappingCollection"]
      ["636404903145791477"]["background"]["bgImage"];
    }
}
```

Comment: the above code is right. But the problem this is hard coded value. I want to store bgColor value in color variable. How to fetch the path from json file so we can store the values according to our need.  So we didn't hard code the value as json file always changes.

Comment: @RajeshRamtere You can assign this value two any variable using the assignment operator like `$scope.bgColor = styleObj["styleMapping"]["1"]["StyleMappingCollection"]
      ["636404903145791477"]["background"]["bgImage"];` or `sliderCtrlPtr.bgColor= styleObj["styleMapping"]["1"]["StyleMappingCollection"]
      ["636404903145791477"]["background"]["bgImage"];` What issue are you facing?

Comment: If my 636404903145791477 is different now, then how i can retrieve that parameter. Consider i am getting diffrerent json file always. and this number is also changing. Now i want to get gata dynamically

Comment: @RajeshRamtere You need to loop through the keys like so. `for( x in styleObj["styleMapping"]["1"]["StyleMappingCollection"]){
 sliderCtrlPtr.bgColor = styleObj["styleMapping"]["1"]["StyleMappingCollection"]
      [x]["background"]["bgColor"];
}
` I am assuming you are having only one property in the question that's "636404903145791477"

Comment: No i have multiple keys like 636404903145791477, 63640490314574523, 636404903145791123 etc. depending upon how user add particular button.

Comment: @Do you want the first one only? If not assign the backgrounds to an array and acces

Comment: i want to store all key's bgColor or bgImage in variables

Comment: @RajeshRamtere Yeah so do like this?

`sliderCtrlPtr.bgColor = [];
sliderCtrlPtr.bgImage = [];

for (x in styleObj["styleMapping"]["1"]["StyleMappingCollection"]) {
  sliderCtrlPtr.bgColor.push(styleObj["styleMapping"]["1"]["StyleMappingCollection"][x]["background"]["bgColor"]);
  sliderCtrlPtr.bgImage.push(styleObj["styleMapping"]["1"]["StyleMappingCollection"][x]["background"]["bgImage"]);
}
` I don't understand what the issue you are facing is?

Answer (score 1):

Dot notation:

First you need to parse the JSON with

```
obj = JSON.parse(json);
```

Since the JSON contains objects, you then use the dot notation, e.g.

```
var backColor = obj.StyleMappingCollection.background.bgcolor;
```

The thing is, those numeric field names in the JSON could cause problems in using this.

This is en excerpt from a program I've written, in which I have a partners.json file (which contains nested objects in different levels) and I want to store the JSON offices field in an object.

The JSON file is in this form:

```
    [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "urlName": "test-url",
        "organization": "Test Organization",
        "customerLocations": "Global",
        "willWorkRemotely": true,
        "website": "http://www.testurl.com/",
        "services": "This is a test services string",
        "offices": [
          {
            "location": "Random, Earth",
            "address": "Randomness 42, 109 Some St \nRandomville 2000",
            "coordinates": "-33.8934219,151.20404600000006"
          }
        ]
      }, {"id": 2, ... }]
```

I import the JSON in my JavaScript code:

```
/* import partner information from the supplied JSON file */
var partners = require('./partners.json');
```

And then I parse and stringify the required "offices" fields accordingly:

```
/* extract all office locations */
var officeLocations = {};
for (var i = 0; i < partners.length; i++) {
    officeLocations[i] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(partners[i].offices));
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Plz share me with example. How i can do it this in my code

Comment: How i can get all json data. So i should get JSON objects

Comment: This example fits perfectly what you are trying to do: https://www.mkyong.com/javascript/how-to-access-json-object-in-javascript/

Comment: But i have dynamically generated data i.e. json file data.. Then how i can use json string?

Comment: I added an example in my answer